# external links css: text links vs img links

Tags: css

I have `:after` content for external links to show the arrow icon like on wiki.

```
a[href^="https://"]
:not([href*="mysite.com"])
:after{
content: "  "   url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAVklEQVR4Xn3PgQkAMQhDUXfqTu7kTtkpd5RA8AInfArtQ2iRXFWT2QedAfttj2FsPIOE1eCOlEuoWWjgzYaB/IkeGOrxXhqB+uA9Bfcm0lAZuh+YIeAD+cAqSz4kCMUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);    
}
```

However, I also have links that are images, not text. for those i don't want `:after` content, I want shadow on hover instead, but i can't figure out how to do it.

Most of these image links are stacked together with no text links and no non-link images mixed in, so i could wrap them in divs and style those divs to remove :after content for all links and add shadow on hover for all images. but that's nesting needless divs, plus it would mean no image links outside of such divs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:empty will check for **any** content inside, including text, so that will not work unless one of his links are totally empty (no text, no children). It would be nice if you could provide an example of your code with and without images.

An alternative without nesting divs would be to simply add a class when you have a link that has an image, if you're nesting the `<img>` inside it. Then simply style that differently.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think to give examples of text/img links. Text links are:
   <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>

Image links are:
   <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>

Comment: Unfortunately css does not have any selector besides :empty to check for what is inside an element, and then move back to select something outside, so your simplest option would be to add a class to your image links (which I imagine must be less used, so it's easier to keep adding classes, but either way works). You can either do this manually or use js to check automatically if there is an image inside a link, and then add a class if yes. Both are valid options, I'd say you should consider what is best for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll add classes. Most of these are php-generated, the few lose ones I can do manually.